# Customized Masked input

Tags: javascript, jquery, masking

I need a utility for a text box so that by default it have 60 or may be more '.' characters, as the user types in dots '.' will be replaced by the user input and if user presses backspace his character will be replaced by dot '.' i am using [this](http://digitalbush.com/projects/masked-input-plugin/) for applying masking on textbox, but it is not working as per the expectation can i you please suggest me how to alter this or may be any other script or code.

code i have applied is

```
 $('.desc-odd input').mask("**************************************************************************************************************", { placeholder: "." });
```

Comment: [Works fine for me](http://jsfiddle.net/jVC8r/), what exactly is your problem?

Comment: i have to click on textbox inorder to make it work.

Comment: It appears that is by design and there is no documentation that suggests you can change that. Maybe you should contact their support directly

Comment: @musefan i don't exaactly need this plugin do you have any other alternate for it?